# Fit an image inside of a link inside of a div of a specific size

Tags: css, tailwind-css

How do you fit an image inside of a link inside of a div, without the link growing to the size of the div?

As an example, here's a solution (using Tailwind) that visually looks okay:

```html
<div class="mb-12 h-[200px] w-[280px] bg-pink-500">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="img" class="h-full w-full object-contain" />
  </a>
</div>
```

[image]

https://play.tailwindcss.com/BbZvEFCr6A

But this causes the entire pink background to be clickable instead of only the image. I don't want that to happen, the link should "hug" the image. The image can be any size, portrait or landscape, and I don't know the sizes beforehand, so using fixed pixels won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Don't define fixed size for the image. Define max-width/height instead

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  
  /* to debug */
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box a {
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}

.box a img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="img"  >
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: While that works great for portrait images, it doesn't center landscape images vertically. And combining this with flex seems to break the horizontal centering.

Comment: It's buggy in Safari, where the image isn't always horizontally centered, very strange.